# Live streaming camera and microphone input on a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: audio, video, alsa, streaming, ffmpeg

I got a a Raspberry Pi camera and a USB microphone connected to the Raspberry Pi 4. All of them are working seperately. But now, I would like to stream them live and combined for accessing it in HTML. The video must also be flipped horizontally and in the bottom right corner should be the timestamp displayed.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
I found already this command:

```
raspivid -rot 180 -t 0 -w 320 -h 240 -fps 24 -b 5000000 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -strict -2 test.flv
```

Is it possible to live stream the outputted flv file to access on a browser?

Comment: probably yes ... linux is very flexible ... i don't think that it would be a waste of time to do research ... good luck with your project .... come back and ask a question if you encounter problems

Comment: don't limit your chances of success by researching about Raspberry Pi ... it is a Linux question, not RPi

Comment: there are multiple ways of doing this - you'll need an encoder to multiplex and encode the audio+video into a stream, then you may need a source client to send the stream to some sort of stream server, then you'll need this stream server to handle the incoming stream and "serve" it in a way that a browser can consume it